# Getting this Exception - "property storage cannot find expected per-thread storage data"

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am getting this error "property storage cannot find expected per-thread storage data" in this line of code.

"self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)"

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when calling:
`_player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:URL];`
I solved it by making sure the code is running in the main thread.